# Retrieving call log from Twilio using the Python Rest API

Tags: python-2.7, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to retrieve a list of calls completed after 1/1/2017 to now.  Based on the documentation I tried:

```
calls=client.calls.list(started_after=date(2017,1,1))
for call in calls:
    print("Call to: {} call from {} duration {}".format(call.to,call.from_, call.duration))
```

I'm retrieving a call log but all I'm getting is the calls for the current day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe the sort order for the [list of calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call) is in reverse chronological order, so you are getting the most recent calls first. All [list resources from Twilio are paginated](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information) in order to retrieve more. The default page size is 50.

You can turn the `pageSize` up to 1000 at the most to get more records in one API call.

```
calls=client.calls.list(started_after=date(2017,1,1), page_size=1000)
```

Or, you can use the [Python helper library's](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) [`iter` method, to iterate over the list of calls](http://twilio-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/basics.html?highlight=iter#listing-all-resources), making all the API calls you need to fetch all the data.

```
calls=client.calls.iter(started_after=date(2017,1,1))
```

Let me know if that helps.